# Robotframework cannot import name SYSTEM_ENCODING

Tags: python, importerror, robotframework

I would like to start with automated testing and I'm trying to work with this tool called Robot Framework.
As far as I know I installed every dependency that was needed. (Followed a guide online)
But when I start Robot Framework I get the following error:
[image]

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Thank you :-)

Comment: If possible, you might want to upgrade your Python to 2.7. I don't know if this will fix the error (probably not), but Python 2.6 is quite old.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I received some testlibraries and these only work on python 2.6 so at the moment I can't upgrade.

Comment: clarification "when I start robot framework" is incorrect -- this is a RIDE error, not a robot error. RIDE and robot framework are two different products. You can run robot without RIDE.